# GWT 2.6 Console Warnings

Tags: java, gwt

What does these warnings mean?

```
[WARN] Server class 'org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.listener.ELContextCleaner' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/Applications/gwt/gwt-2.6.0/gwt-dev.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
   For additional info see: file:/Applications/gwt/gwt-2.6.0/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
[WARN] Server class 'org.slf4j.Logger' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS3.5M1/buddyis/lib/gwt/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
   For additional info see: file:/Applications/gwt/gwt-2.6.0/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
[WARN] Server class 'org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS3.5M1/buddyis/lib/gwt/mobile/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
   For additional info see: file:/Applications/gwt/gwt-2.6.0/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
[WARN] Server class 'org.apache.log4j.Level' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS3.5M1/buddyis/lib/gwt/mobile/log4j-1.2.17.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
   For additional info see: file:/Applications/gwt/gwt-2.6.0/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.eclipse.jetty.util.log).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first set of WARNings are because when you run dev-mode, it starts a servlet container (Jetty) which is configured by default to use any library in your project classpath when a class-not-found happens.
Those warnings are useful to know what libraries you must add to your .war artifact in production.

The second set of WARNings are because you have not configured log4j for your project yet.